# gvim: visual mode movement broken

Tags: vim

This is probably a result of too many plugins but I can't figure out which one.

So normally Vj or Vk in normal mode would highlight two lines. The behavior now is this:

1. When V is pressed, the whole line is highlighted. OK
2. When k or j is pressed, the visual block is removed and replaced with k or j. :(

I checked vmap and no strange mapping is configured with these keys.

If I use arrow keys instead of kjlh, then things are fine.

My gvim version is 7.4. In console vim, it works fine.

Any clue to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you check `xmap` and `xmap <buffer>` and `vmap <buffer>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are going into select mode instead of visual mode.  When select mode is active typing anything "printable" removes the selected text, enters insert mode, and inserts the character(s) you typed.

You need to check the value of the `'selectmode'` option and what file set it by running this command, including the question mark as part of the command:

```
:verbose set selectmode?
```

Then you can configure, modify, or disable the plugin/script that is doing this.

Alternatively if you want to keep this behavior, you can toggle between visual and select mode when text his highlighted by pressing <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd>